# Puppeteer upload videos to TikTok

Tags: web-scraping, puppeteer, tiktok

I'm having trouble getting the TikTok upload page to show up when I use Puppeteer to upload videos. even using Puppeteer-extra and Puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth in my packages to avoid bot detection, it appears that TikTok is still identifying me as one. I've tried using a lot of browsers, including Firefox, Chrome, Edge, and Brave, but none of them have worked well.

The empty upload page causes me to believe that TikTok considers what I do as automated. I need advice on what steps I should take to solve this issue. I have so far thought about switching the User-Agent to look like a real browser and enabling JavaScript in Puppeteer. But I'm still unsure of the best course of action.

https://i.imgur.com/7IsA4pN.png